# How to add values to several Sets

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, set

I have currently trying to extract from database to be able to put values to various sets. e.g.

- If the word is only a single word and has the boolean set to True ->
  Add to SINGLE_POSITIVE
- If the word is only a single word and has the boolean set to False ->
  Add to SINGLE_POSITIVE
- If the word is more than one word and has the boolean set to True ->
  Add to MULTIPLE_POSITIVE
- If the word is more than one word and has the boolean set to False ->
  Add to MULTIPLE_NEGATIVE

So I have created something like this:

```
from typing import Tuple, Set

MOCK_DATABASE = [
    {"python": True},
    {"no": True},
    {"hello world": True},
    {"java": False},
    {"ruby js": False},
    {"c#": False}
]

SINGLE_POSITIVE: Set[str] = {}
MULTI_POSITIVE: Tuple[Set[str], ...] = ()
SINGLE_NEGATIVE: Set[str] = {}
MULTI_NEGATIVE: Tuple[Set[str], ...] = ()

for database_value in MOCK_DATABASE:
    for att, value in database_value.items():
        if value and ' ' in att:
            MULTI_POSITIVE.add(att)
        elif value:
            SINGLE_POSITIVE.add(att)
        elif not value and ' ' in att:
            MULTI_NEGATIVE.add(att)
        else:
            SINGLE_NEGATIVE.add(att)

print(f"Single positive: {SINGLE_POSITIVE}")
print(f"Multi positive: {MULTI_POSITIVE}")
print(f"Single negative: {SINGLE_NEGATIVE}")
print(f"Multi negative: {MULTI_NEGATIVE}")
```

Wanted output:

```
SINGLE_POSITIVE: Set[str] = {
    "python",
    "no",
}
MULTI_POSITIVE: Tuple[Set[str], ...] = (
    {"hello", "world"},
)

SINGLE_NEGATIVE: Set[str] = {
    "java",
    "c#",
}
MULTI_NEGATIVE: Tuple[Set[str], ...] = (
    {"ruby", "js"},
)
```

However when I execute the script, I get an error saying:

```
SINGLE_POSITIVE.add(att)
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'add'
```

My question is, how can I set it so I have the wanted output?

EDIT:

Thanks for the small fix from the answers below:

I have now changed to `SINGLE_POSITIVE: Set[str] = set()`

but that returns now

```
    MULTI_POSITIVE.add(att)
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'add'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a few issues in the code:

1. Per codebreach's answer, you have to initialize the set using `set()`.
2. You can't add elements to tuples; they're immutable. Your best bet is to initialize the `MULTI` variables as lists, then convert them at the end.
3. You need to `split` the keys to get them as multiple separated elements in the set.

```
from typing import List, Tuple, Set

MOCK_DATABASE = [
    {"python": True},
    {"no": True},
    {"hello world": True},
    {"java": False},
    {"ruby js": False},
    {"c#": False},
]

SINGLE_POSITIVE: Set[str] = set()
MULTI_POSITIVE: List[Set[str]] = []
SINGLE_NEGATIVE: Set[str] = set()
MULTI_NEGATIVE: List[Set[str]] = []

for database_value in MOCK_DATABASE:
    for att, value in database_value.items():
        if value and " " in att:
            MULTI_POSITIVE.append(set(att.split()))
        elif value:
            SINGLE_POSITIVE.add(att)
        elif not value and " " in att:
            MULTI_NEGATIVE.append(set(att.split()))
        else:
            SINGLE_NEGATIVE.add(att)

MULTI_POSITIVE_TUP = tuple(MULTI_POSITIVE)
MULTI_NEGATIVE_TUP = tuple(MULTI_NEGATIVE)

print(f"Single positive: {SINGLE_POSITIVE}")
print(f"Multi positive: {MULTI_POSITIVE_TUP}")
print(f"Single negative: {SINGLE_NEGATIVE}")
print(f"Multi negative: {MULTI_NEGATIVE_TUP}")
```

Gives:

```
Single positive: {'python', 'no'}
Multi positive: ({'hello', 'world'},)
Single negative: {'c#', 'java'}
Multi negative: ({'js', 'ruby'},)
```

---

Just another point, on reflection, there's another issue that's more design-wise than programmatical. There's no reason for your `MOCK_DATABASE` to be a list of dictionaries, rather than a single dictionary. A dictionary can have several `key: value` pairs and I can't think of a single example (off the top of my head) where it's useful to define a dictionary with one entry. If this `MOCK_DATABASE` is more complex than the one in your example, you might consider using the [pandas library](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/getting_started/intro_tutorials/01_table_oriented.html#min-tut-01-tableoriented).

Comment: This is awesome! I guess I need to do quite alot to convert it the way I wanted but this worked very well! and also do make sense as well!

Comment: Glad it helped :) please consider [accepting this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you have type hints that say `SINGLE_POSITIVE` and `SINGLE_NEGATIVE` are `Set`s but your code is initializing them to a `dict`

```py
SINGLE_POSITIVE: Set[str] = {}

# should become 

SINGLE_POSITIVE: Set[str] = set()
```

Comment: Ahhh make sense! Yes. Ahh thats right... now I will get a new error :(

```MULTI_POSITIVE.add(att) AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'add'```

my guess is that I need to somehow split the words so it be something like: `{'hello', 'world'}` but not idea how...